# Why element is not getting rendered and how can I fix it?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am trying to render some `dynamic data` in an element using `useEffect Hook`, which is not working.

Below is `abc.tsx` which has `byTestOne(globalThis.test)` which is responsible to send data back to us using `globalThis.test` value

```
const abc = () => {
const [data, setData] = useState<any>([]);
// globalThis.test is something that changes and when it changes, byTestOne triggers and get the data based on globalThis.test
useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
        const data = byTestOne(globalThis.test).then((data: any) => {
            return data
        })
        setData(await data)
    }
    fetchData();
}, [globalThis.test]);

return (
    <ImageBackground
        source={require("../assets/images/abc.png")}
        style={styles.bg}>
        <View style={styles.containerHome}>
            <CardStack>
                {
                    // Below Element is not getting rendered
                    data.map((item: any) => (
                        <Card key={item.id}>
                            <CardItemForSwiper
                                name={item.name}
                                description={item.description}
                            />
                        </Card>
                    )
                    )
                }
            </CardStack>
        </View>
    </ImageBackground>
);
};

export default ABC;
```

**byTestOne() looks like this:**

```
    let data = [{
    name: "test1",
    description: "desc",
    test: "one"
},
{
    name: "test2",
    description: "desc",
    test: "two"
}]
export const byTestOne = (test: string) => {
    const dataA = new Promise((resolve) => {
        const filData = data.filter((rawData) => {
            return rawData.test == test
        })
        if (filData.length > 0) {
            globalThis.test = test
        }
        return resolve(filData)
    })
    return dataA
}
```

Comment: What isn't working about it? And what is `globalThis`?

Comment: Element is not getting rendered... `globalThis.test` is something that changes .. and I see there is no issue with globalThis because I am able to console the response

Comment: Try moving the await out of the setData, it must be like: `const data = await byTestOne`

Comment: Tried, not working still :(

Comment: It worked when I change `const [data, setData] = useState<any>([])` to `const [data, setData] = useState<any>([{}])`.. still digging to know whats happening.

Answer (score 0):

`const filData = data.filter((rawData) => { return rawData.test == test })`
what value is test? Fromenter code here the code snippet test could be undefined hence it's returning an empty array

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).